# SQL calculating average on an occurrence within a set

Tags: sql, function

I have a dataset for a school project that consists of a set of movies and genres they belong to. a movie can belong to more than one genre and each is one row in the table (id is pk). e.g. a small sample

```
1  Taken  Action
2  Sherlock Holmes Mystery
3  Sherlock Holmes Action
4  Predator        Horror
5  Predator        Action
6  Omen            Horror
7  Pink Panther    Comedy
```

How would I find that for a given Genre, what is the average number of Genres that a movie in that genre is in. e.g. on an average a movie in Horror Genre is in 1.5 Genres.

Generally I am used to doing averages on items like salary, numbers but this is slightly different

Comment: What have you tried? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: To improve the quality of your question please refer to what research you have performed (with links to anything you found to be particularly helpful).  Please show us the fields in each table, preferably with sample data as well.  Please show us what coding you have attempted and the full text of any error messages it is producing.  Please show us the form of your desired output (based on your sample data).  For more information, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Also, please include a tag for the form of `SQL` that you are using, e.g. `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT genreListGenre,
       AVG( movieGenreCount ) AS genreMean
FROM ( SELECT genreList.genre AS genreListGenre,
              genreList.movieID AS genreListMovie,
              COUNT( moreGenres.genre ) AS movieGenreCount
       FROM movies AS genreList
       JOIN movies AS moreGenres ON genreList.movieName = moreGenres.movieName
       GROUP BY genreList.genre,
                genreList.movieID
     ) AS genreListGenerator
GROUP BY genreListGenre
ORDER BY genreListGenre;
```

The inner query joins one instance of `movies` to another of the same table.  So that the fields from each may still be referred to without confusion, each instance is given an alias, `genreList` and `moreGenres`.  The purpose of the join is to develop a list comprising each `genre`, each `movieID` associated with that `genre`, and each `genre` associated with that `movieID`'s corresponding `movieName`.  The first two fields can be determined from one instance of `movies`, and the third can be drawn from the second instance and is dependent on the value of `movieName` from the first instance, hence the join being on the shared value of `movieName`.

Once the list is formed it is grouped by `genreList.genre` and `genreList.movieID` and a count of each related genre (`moreGenres.genre`) for that group is made.

The outer query takes the fields returned by the inner query and groups them by `genre` and for each `genre` calculates a mean average of the count of each `genre` associated with each `movie` that is associated with that group's `genre`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Addendum*

This code was tested against an instance of `movies` created (in MySQL) using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE movies
(
    movieID     INT,
    movieName   VARCHAR( 50 ),
    genre       VARCHAR( 20 )
);
INSERT INTO movies ( movieID,
                     movieName,
                     genre )
VALUES ( 1, 'Taken',           'Action'  ),
       ( 2, 'Sherlock Holmes', 'Mystery' ),
       ( 3, 'Sherlock Holmes', 'Action'  ),
       ( 4, 'Predator',        'Horror'  ),
       ( 5, 'Predator',        'Action'  ),
       ( 6, 'Omen',            'Horror'  ),
       ( 7, 'Pink Panther',    'Comedy'  );
```

Comment: I recommend that you investigate *normalisation* of your table in relation each `movie` and the many `genre`'s that it can have associated with it.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please note that if an Answer addresses all the points of a Question that you post and does solve the problem, and if it is the most suitable Answer available, then you can click on the tick near the top of the Answer to accept it as the Answer.  This will give the Answerer a 15 point reward and remove the Question from StackOverfow's list of unanswered Questions.